# Should I render all the frames every secound?

Tags: html5-canvas, rendering

I'm programming a 2D game with HTML5 canvas. so it won't take a lot of time for rendering all the objects and frames.

I want to ask about both 2D and 3D games.

Suppose that I made a change or more on one of the objects.should I render all the objects when I only need to redraw that object? is rendering all objects and frames is the only option? and if the game was 3D, won't rendering take a lot of time?  <s>specially on slow internet connections</s>

Comment: Rendering time and connection speed aren't related. You could have a 56k modem with the latest nVidia graphics card, or a fibre-optic line with an [S3 Trio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_Trio).

Comment: That second half of the question doesn't show a big understanding of how rendering on a HTML5 canvas work. Do you render using Javascript in the browser? Than it totally doesn't matter how your server connection is.

Comment: so it depends only on the browser and computer of the user. thanks for the tip :)

Comment: It depends entirely on your scenario - there is no magic one-solution to this (unfortunately). Partial drawn may be faster, but how many, at one point redrawing all are faster... cache often, etc. etc. The only way to find out is to performance test often, e.g. when you try out different combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So [performance] depends only on the browser and computer of the user.

If  you are making a game which is played simultaneously across several computers then the connection speed is important. Otherwise, the connection speed is mostly irrelevant (except as it relates to initially downloading your game resources). A better CPU/GPU, memory on the local computer will most affect your app performance.

**About performance**

In theory, you get better performance if you redraw only those game items which have changed since the last frame.

In practice, redrawing one game item often requires redrawing multiple other game items. You might want to redraw the player who moved, but in doing so you must also redraw the background plus any other game items colliding with the player.

As a result, it's often better to clear the entire canvas and redraw all the game items in their current position. So the unsatisfying answer to your question is that you should test your unique game app to determine if you can efficiently redraw just changed items or if a complete redrawing is faster.